Autofs configuration on RHEL9: NFS directories appear empty despite successful mount
I am trying to set up my NFS system between my server node and my client node running on rhel9. They are both on different physical servers on the same network. The nfs-server daemon is properly running on my server node and showmount -e returns:
Export list for host:
/mnt/name1      x.x.x.0/16
/mnt/name2      x.x.x.0/16
/mnt/name3      x.x.x.0/16

Here is the /etc/exports file on the server:
/mnt/name1 x.x.x.0/16(rw,sync,no_root_squash,no_subtree_check)
/mnt/name2 x.x.x.0/16(rw,sync,no_root_squash,no_subtree_check)
/mnt/name3 x.x.x.0/16(rw,sync,no_root_squash,no_subtree_check)

Here is the status for the autofs daemon on the client node:
● autofs.service - Automounts filesystems on demand
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/autofs.service; enabled; preset: disabled)
     Active: active (running) since Wed 2024-06-05 16:15:16 CDT; 5s ago
   Main PID: 739859 (automount)
      Tasks: 5 (limit: 98138)
     Memory: 3.8M
        CPU: 42ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/autofs.service
             └─739859 /usr/sbin/automount --systemd-service --dont-check-daemon

Jun 05 16:15:16 host systemd[1]: Starting Automounts filesystems on demand...
Jun 05 16:15:16 host automount[739859]: setautomntent: lookup(sss): setautomountent: entry for map auto.master not found
Jun 05 16:15:16 host automount[739859]: setautomntent: lookup(sss): setautomountent: entry for map auto_master not found
Jun 05 16:15:16 host systemd[1]: Started Automounts filesystems on demand.

Here is /etc/auto.master:
/-   /etc/auto.nfs-shares

Here is auto.nfs-shares:
/mnt/name1   -fstype=nfs,rw,soft  x.x.x.0:/mnt/name1
/mnt/name2   -fstype=nfs,rw,soft  x.x.x.0:/mnt/name2
/mnt/name3   -fstype=nfs,rw,soft  x.x.x.0:/mnt/name3

On the client node, when I execute mount, it returns among other things:
/etc/auto.nfs-shares on /mnt/name1 type autofs (rw,relatime,fd=7,pgrp=739859,timeout=300,minproto=5,maxproto=5,direct,pipe_ino=1745483)
/etc/auto.nfs-shares on /mnt/name2 type autofs (rw,relatime,fd=7,pgrp=739859,timeout=300,minproto=5,maxproto=5,direct,pipe_ino=1745483)
/etc/auto.nfs-shares on /mnt/name3 type autofs (rw,relatime,fd=7,pgrp=739859,timeout=300,minproto=5,maxproto=5,direct,pipe_ino=1745483)

The files name1, name2, and name3 show up when I use ls /mnt/ but I cannot access the files due to "no such file or directory" or them being empty (they have test files in them). Any suggestions would be appreciated.

What output do you get after stopping the autofs service and running the daemon manually using automount -vfd?

Check in /etc/sssd/sssd.conf and make sure you have
[sssd]
services = nss,pam,autofs

Without the autofs in the services, I got the error message:
setautomntent: lookup(sss): setautomountent: entry for map auto.master not found

